# Web page loading problem on RealTek Semiconductor RTL8168/8111 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet NIC

Tags: networking, drivers, kubuntu, realtek

I have a problem with my network (RealTek Semiconductor RTL8168/8111 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet NIC) on Kubuntu (Live CD). I wanted to install Kubuntu, so I tested the web browser using the Live CD, but Facebook, Youtube, and others sites are not displayed properly! How I resolve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu.com. Please be more specific. What exactly is wrong with the way the sites are displayed? Can you post a screenshot? Which browser do you use? Which version of Kubuntu? What makes you think the problem is in the network card?

Comment: Facebook.com,youtube.com and others don t displayed properly! The version of Kubuntu is 12.04.4 x64 and I use the default browser of Kubuntu and I don t know how because the problem.Only google.com is displayed really well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook and YouTube require 3rd party addons that aren't needed in the Windows world.  Since Google is working there is nothing wrong with your connection.  If you decide to install KUbuntu, on the 1st screen after the welcome screen, check both boxes (Install Third Party Software) and (Download Updates while Installing).

After installing, use Ubuntu Software Center to install the last version of Flash, plus the Chromium browser and pepper flash.

Comment: I checking after installing,upgrade and dist-upgrade.Is a problem with my internet card.Ubuntu team resolved this problem?Is here a old tutorial:http://www.twm-kd.com/linux/realtek-rtl81688111e-and-ubuntu-linux/. And I have a LiveUSB with Kubuntu maked with Unetbootin